# Adicionar uma palavra fixa numa URL amigável

Tags: php, mysql, htaccess

Boa noite,

Estou a fazer uma pesquisa e estou a ter um problema em passar o valor que e escrito na `input` para outra pagina onde o resultado irá ser apresentado.

**Exemplo Url que estou a tentar passar os valores**

```
http://exemplo.com/locais/pesquisa?q=bares
```

**Ficheiro .htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^locais/([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)$  index.php?controller=pesquisa?q=$1
```

Mas sempre me retorna o nome pesquisa e não o que digitei na `input`

**Form**

```
<form method="post" id="pesquisa_home" name="pesquisa_home" action="locais/pesquisa/<?= $_POST['valor_pesquisa'] ?>" >
          <div style="margin-left:150px;">
              <div style="float:left; width:500px;"><input id="valor_pesquisa" name="valor_pesquisa" type="text" placeholder="Restaurantes, bares, hotéis..." /></div>
              <div style="float:left; margin-left:5px;"><input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" /></div>
          </div> 
        </form>
```

Comment: use a url assim: http://exemplo.com/locais/bares

Comment: mas nao da para usar daquela forma ?

Comment: é possível mas precisa mudar a regra rewriterule para ignorar a palavra pesquisa.. Preferi não comentar isso porque eu sugiro que mantenha a url mais curta possível.. A palavra "pequisa" se torna desnecessária pois é apenas o nome do parâmetro. Mas se vc tiver um motivo específico, então, basta incluiar o termo na regra

Comment: Mas nao da para passar o paramento q como na url ficar assim http://exemplo.com/locais/pesquisa?q=bares

Comment: mas e qual o motivo em enviar o parâmetro dessa forma ? Afinal vc quer url amigável ou url normal ?

Comment: como comentei acima, é possível fazer isso... acho que vc quer fazerr não é url amigável, é meramente um "roteamento".

Comment: Tem razão peço desculpe a esta hora e a programar dia e noite já não estou bom da cabeça

Comment: Eu quero e url amigável

Comment: Se o termo *pesquisa* é fixo, só precisa colocar na sua regra.

Comment: tirar o pesquisa certo ? e deixar so locais/bares ?

Comment: ficaria assim: RewriteRule ^locais/pesquisa/([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)$  index.php?controller=pesquisa?q=$1

Comment: aí vc acessa o link assim: endereço.do.site/locais/pesquisa/bares

Comment: mas eu agora ao pesquisar ele sempre me adiciona o ? na url assim quebra a url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua regra `^locais/([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)$` diz que o que tiver depois de `locais/` no caso `pesquisa` vai ser o valor da variável `q` que recebe o primeiro valor `$1`.

No caso sua URL `http://exemplo.com/locais/pesquisa?q=bares` disse que a variável `q` recebe `bares`, porém sua regra está mudando o valor para `pesquisa` que é o termo logo após a `/` da regra.

Você pode corrigir mudando a regra para: `^locais/pesquisa/([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)$`
e sua URL ficando `http://exemplo.com/locais/pesquisa/bares`

Ou apenas tirando o termo `pesquisa` da URL como já dito pelo @Daniel Omine, ficando: 
`http://exemplo.com/locais/bares`.

Comment: E isso ambas estão correctas coloco o certo a quem ? pois nem me apercebi quem colocou primeiro acho que foi o Daniel Omine mas ele nao colocou como resposta

Comment: mas eu agora ao pesquisar ele sempre me adiciona o ? na url assim quebra a url

Comment: Apesar da intenção da resposta ser boa, creio que não resolve o problema do autor, pois aparentemente trata-se do método GET, que sempre terá o '?q='. Não adianta querer usar URL amigável nesse caso (o que, por sua vez, ja é problema da pergunta). Provavelmente a solução do @DanielOmine é a que se aplica.

Comment: discordo Bacco, pois nem ao menos está claro o que o autor da pergunta quer. EStá ambíguo... Eu acredito que ele queira manter o uso de query normal na URL e apenas adicionar uma rota virtual com a palavra "pesquisa".  Mas ele fala de URL amigável tornando o assunto ambíguo... Então, o autor é quem pode definir isso mas ele se mostra muito confuso

Comment: @DanielOmine Se discorda, mostre como usar a solução do Kadu com GET pra mim (com URL amigavel), e eu peço desculpas. Gosto de aprender coisas novas.

Comment: @DanielOmine Veja o que acha disso, talvez dê pra melhorar essa idéia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54791/problema-com-submit-de-form?noredirect=1#comment112338_54791

Comment: Ainda nao conseguir perceber porque nao da para tirar esse ? do submit

Comment: @CésarSousa se voce usa form com GET, o navegador precisa por isso no URL, é o padrão do método. Se não usa GET, precisa explicar pra nós como está fazendo. Sugeriria acrescentar na pergunta a linha do <form>.

Comment: Já adicionei como estou a tentar fazer agora não aparece o ? mas apresenta o valor que coloquei na input

Comment: CésarSousa agora melhorou pra entender o que você quer, mas bares é uma subcategoria, ou é o que a pessoa digitou? Você quer um POST com subcategorias. Aí ficou mais interessante ainda, pq não precisa do ? em lugar nenhum. @DanielOmine tá acompanhando? Acho que o problema ficou mais interessante.

Comment: bares e o que a pessoa digitou o que pode ser qualquer outra coisa

Comment: Consegue perceber agora o que pretendo eu não estou a usar o ? eu quero que o que a pessoa digitou seja enviado assim exemplo.pt/locais/pesquisa/o que a pessoa digitou percebeu ?

Comment: hehe agora complicou mais. Você quer enviar pelo método POST ? Em primeiro lugar, quando envia pelo método POST não precisa de URL amigável. Mas ainda acho que vc está causando outra confusão de termos referindo-se a "postagem de dados" usando o termo "POST" ao invés de estar referindo-se ao método POST em si.

Comment: lol... acho que estou quase compreendendo.. você diz que esse sinal de interrogação é adicinoado automaticamente mas vc não quer ter a interrogação, certo?

Comment: daí vc fala sobre querer enviar pelo método POST (é o que pressuponho), então acho que o problema é que falta definir o método de envio no formulário <form method="POST" action="...">

Comment: Resolvi agora mesmo

Comment: @DanielOmine bem observado o problema da terminologia. Provavelmente eu devia ter exemplificado o POST em vez de mencionar apenas. Mas o bom é que ele resolveu, creio que depois do seu comment.

Comment: Não foi através da sugestão do papa charlie

Answer (score 0):

**Solução**

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="">
<div style="margin-left:150px;">
    <div style="float:left; width:500px;"><input style="height: 38px;" id="valor_pesquisa" name="valor_pesquisa" type="text" placeholder="Restaurantes, bares, hotéis..." /></div>
    <div style="float:left; margin-left:5px;"><input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" /></div>
</div> 
</form>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function(e) {
        if($('#valor_pesquisa').val() === ''){
            $("#form").attr("action", "http://sabeonde.pt/locais/pesquisa/todos");
        }else{
          var valor_pesquisa = $("#valor_pesquisa").val();
          $("#form").attr("action", "http://sabeonde.pt/locais/pesquisa/"+valor_pesquisa);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Só como complemento: Nesse caso é bom conferir sempre o valor do `$_POST['valor_pesquisa']` dentro do PHP, pois mesmo que o URL não mude (no caso de JS desligado) vai funcionar bem. (comentei isso caso algum leitor pense em usar a solução pegando o termo só do URL)