# Problema com submit de form

Tags: php

Boa noite,

Tenho um `form` de pesquisa em que ele resgata o valor escrito na `input` e envia para outra pagina esse valor para mostrar os resultados, o problema que estou a ter e que eu uso url amigável para enviar o valor essa parte esta a funcionar o problema e que sempre que faço submit do `form` ele adiciona na url sempre o id da `input` e o valor.

**Exemplo erro**

```
http://sabeonde.pt/locais/pesquisa/?pesquisa=teste
```

**Quando ela deveria de ficar assim:**

```
http://sabeonde.pt/locais/pesquisa/teste
```

**Codigo**

```
 <form action="locais/pesquisa/<?= $_REQUEST['pesquisa'] ?>"/>
          <div style="margin-left:150px;">
              <div style="float:left; width:500px;"><input id="pesquisa" name="pesquisa" type="text" placeholder="Restaurantes, bares, hotéis..." /></div>
              <div style="float:left; margin-left:5px;"><input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" /></div>
          </div> 
        </form>
```

Como posso resolver isto ?

Comment: Creio que o problema é o mesmo da sua pergunta anterior, que tem o problema de não ter tocado no assunto de você estar usando método GET no form ou não. Se usa GET não tem como tirar o `?pesquisa=` da URL sem redirecionamento (o que seria ruim também, gerando uma requisição desnecessária).

Comment: Então quer dizer que não ah maneira de resolver o problema ?

Comment: Ou você usa URL amigável, ou usa GET. (ou alguma gambiarra, o que eu acho pior). Mas veja os comments na outra pergunta, estamos discutindo o assunto na resposta de lá. Se trocar por POST, o termo de pesquisa some e a URL fica amigavel, mas ai nao dá pra fazer bookmark. O que dá pra fazer, como solução intermediária, é aceitar a forma amigável, mas aceitar a forma com ?q= tambem. Assim vc gera os links amigáveis quando precisar, mas pode usar GET. Ou faz um redirect, que deixa tudo amigável, mas custa 1 requisição a mais.

Comment: Provável que a solução dependa de melhorar a pergunta anterior [Adicionar uma palavra fixa numa URL amigável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54787/adicionar-uma-palavra-fixa-numa-url-amig%c3%a1vel) em vez de fazer uma nova.

Comment: Se você quer que o submit envie o input pela URL `http://sabeonde.pt/locais/pesquisa/{input}`, você pode fazer um evento pelo *jQuery* para redirecionar o formulário com o input no final da URL.

Comment: @Bacco, acho que o problema dele é estético, o `/?q=input` não afeta a url amigável - pelo menos não com as minhas definições

Comment: @PapaCharlie eu considerei isso, o problema é temos um paradoxo aqui: se não é GET, como ele comentou, não tem como aparecer um `?q=` em lugar nenhum. Só que se for POST, o que a pessoa digitou ficará só no corpo da requisição, acessivel com $_POST, e não vai aparecer no URL amigável, percebe? Eu creio que a pergunta está misturando o que o autor quer fazer, e o código real dele. Ele disse que quer um POST, mas o form como está na pergunta, por padrão é GET. Nota: Eu gosto de POST por causa da estética também, mas o problema é que não dá bookmark. Vide comment meu na outra pergunta dele.

Comment: @Bacco, Ele quer fazer Post virar Get e Get virar Post :) Ele poderia receber via Post e redirecionar a nova URL formatada, mas cá entre nós...

Comment: @PapaCharlie veja os comments aqui (na resposta tb) se tiver curiosidade: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54787/ ... cheguei a pensar em manipular o history após o POST, mas acho que fica um tanto remendado. E essas coisas de pesquisa quanto menos complica, melhor. Principalmente pq vários navegadores permitem você fazer uma série de pesquisas customizadas em sites de sua preferencia (ao menos o Opera e o Vivaldi são bem práticos nisso).

Comment: é a mesma questão que ele abriu de uma outra forma, explicando tudo muito confuso... Agora eu é que estou confuso...preciso de um psiquiatra;;

Comment: esta feito resolvi